# Magento automatically adds random product to cart, super weird issue

Tags: magento, cookies

I have this website http://www.hageredskap.no. If you try to add any product to cart, you will see it automatically adds one more random product. This only happens at the first add to cart action, not after that.(so you can clear cookie to try again). In admin, these products have no connection. no related, crossell or upsell. Each time it random adds one different product, usually out of stock ones.

So far, what i have tried :
- Disabled all 3rd extensions, all keep core Magento
- Change template to RWD (default)
But it still happens.

I want to hear your theories, please. What might cause this super strange issue? This site has been upgraded from Magento 1.5 to 1.9.1 but i don't remember if this ever happened before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution, just truncate those quote tables

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
truncate sales_flat_quote; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_address; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_address_item; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_item; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_item_option; 
truncate sales_flat_quote_payment; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation with Magento 2.3.3 
This solution works on Magento 2. Just need to change table names accordingly.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Can you explain why deleting data from tables would solve a problem where a random item is in the cart. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why. It just solved the problem which occurred after migration from Magento 1 to 2.